# User input through terminal with input file

Tags: c, input, terminal

So I calculated the mean and standard deviation from double values read within a file.

My file data has 1 number per line: My data in the file is the following

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    
    FILE *inputfile= fopen("file.dat.txt", "r");

    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open text file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    double i; 
    double j=1;
    double average; 
    double stdish=0;
    double stdreal=0; 
    double x=0;
    double sum=0;
    double stdfinal;

    while(fscanf(inputfile, "%lf", &i) != EOF){
        x=x+1;
        sum = sum + i;
        j = i*i;
        stdreal +=j;
    }

    average = sum/x;
    stdish = (stdreal/x)-(average*average);
    stdfinal = sqrt(stdish);

    printf("The average is %.4lf\n", average);
    printf("The standard deviation is %.4lf\n", stdfinal);

    fclose(inputfile);
    return 0;
}
```

I am running this through the terminal.
My data file is file.dat.txt. What I am trying to do is to have the user input the text file through the terminal instead of having it in the program.

Like this: `./sdev < file.dat`

I'm not exactly sure how to implement this in my program...

Thanks!

Comment: You read from `stdin` instead of `inputfile`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the argument passing to the program with `./sdev file.dat`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Your help text here\n");
    }

    FILE *inputfile= fopen(argv[1], "r");

    [...]
```

or if you want to read it with `echo "file.dat" | ./sdev` you have read it with stdin
this could you then extend to read in multiple files.

```
char filename[1024]
if (fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin)) {

    FILE *inputfile= fopen(filename, "r");

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write the main function with argument. So that you can able to pass file name from terminal while invoking the executable file.

See the example program in this path:
http://www.astro.umd.edu/~dcr/Courses/ASTR615/intro_C/node11.html

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do that. The first approach is to accept input via `stdin` by file redirection. This is the approach you proposed:

```
$ ./sdev < file.dat
```

Your program then should read from `stdin` instead of `inputfile`. You can change all occurrences of ´inputfile`to`stdin`, but you could also make`inputfile`a shallow copy to the file handle`stdin`:

```
int main()
{    
    FILE *inputfile = stdin;

    /* do stuff */
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't close `stdin`. It is a system file handle that is managed by the operating system. It is not `NULL`.

The second approach is to specify the file as command line argument:

```
$ ./sdev file.dat
```

Your program must then use the form of `main` that accepts command line parameters. Note that the program name itself is passed as the first parameter, so your file name should be in ´argv[1]`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *inputfile;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: sdev inputfile\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    inputfile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (inputfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s.\n", inputfile);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* do stuff */

    fclose(inputfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, you have to open and close `inputfile` explicitly in your program.